# Asynchronous reaction adding discord

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I recently wanted to create a bot which would react to the message with certain reactions.

```js
 try {
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
        await message.react("");
    } catch (error) {
        //if there was an error while adding a reaction, stop adding them
        return;
    }
```

If I use async after every `message.react()` and I execute the command twice it adds the reaction to the first embed first and then to the second and then to the first and then to the second and it goes like that until it finishes.
But if I use `Promise.all()` then it adds all of the reactions to the first messages first and then adds all of the reactions to the second message. The question is how can I do it so it'll add reactions at the same time for both of the messages. I was also wondering how for example music bots solve this issue when there are tons of users executing their commands and they're adding the reactions simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: I can only see 1 embed not 2, please include a workable example of what you are trying to say.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty sorry for not adding any info, I edited the post so you can see what I mean by that

Comment: JS cannot perform perfectly simultaneous actions, and reactions are heavily rate limited which causes this to be so slow.  You're better off using buttons, either through the [discord-buttons package in v12](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons) or the [built-in functionality in v13](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageButton).